# how can I set a 1 second delay on opening up a drop down hover menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been reading things online for awhile and have not figured out the correct way to use the setTimeout function.. any reason why?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jandrews96/8xtxxk35/2/)

```js
$('.drop-down').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
$('.nav-main li ul').hide().removeClass('.drop-down');
setTimeout(function() {
$('.nav-main li').hover(
  function openDrop() {
    $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(1000);
  }, 
  function closeDrop() {
    $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(1000);
  }
);}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-main" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#welcome">Welcome</a></li>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#about">About</a>
  <ul class="drop-down">
   <li><a href="#about">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#client">Clients</a></li>
   <li><a href="#press">Press</a></li>
   <li><a href="#leadership">Leadership</a></li>
   <li><a href="#twitter">Twitter</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-top"><a href="#contact">Contact</a>    </li>
  </ul>
      
</nav>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use JQuery's delay() method in this case, no need for setTimeout

```
$('ul', this).stop().delay(1000).slideDown(1000);
```

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8xtxxk35/3/

Comment: Ah okay, that function makes a lot more sense! Is there a way to have the delay run, then begin the slidedown() ?

Comment: Actually, got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As @Tim said, you don't need to use setTimeout in this instance.

But just to answer why it wasn't working...

If you *were* to use it (and you really don't need to in this case), the reason it's not working is because of the location of your setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('.nav-main li').hover(
     function openDrop() {
       $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(1000);
     }, 
     function closeDrop() {
       $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(1000);
     }
   );
}, 1000);
```

Here, you're not actually doing anything except for delaying the `hover` handler from being added to the page.

You need to wrap the code you actually want to run with setTimeout:

```
   $('.nav-main li').hover(
     function openDrop() {
       setTimeout(function() {
          $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(1000);
       }, 1000);
     }, 
     function closeDrop() {
       setTimeout(function() {
          $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(1000);
       }, 1000);
     }
   );
```

note there are 2 setTimeouts now, one for each function.

Comment: Okay, so my positioning was off. Why is it better to use a delay() in this case?

Comment: I answered too quickly, didn't even notice setTimeout was in the original example. Good catch and good explanation, thanks.

Comment: @J.Andrews well, setTimeout 'complicates' things unnecessarily and the delay() function is actually made for cases like this where to make it easier to apply effects. There's nothing wrong with using setTimeout (AFAIK), but delay()'s easier and shorter :)